# Flutter + Firebase Cloud Messaging notifications not sending to iOS device

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a flutter app which is have set up with firebase cloud functions. I have configured the APN certificate for the iOS app and I am able to send a test message to the iOS device and I am getting the token fine in the app. However when I try to start a campaign to send it to all my test devices that are running in debug mode through vs code the iOS campaign says 0 sends and no device receive a notification where as the android campaign is received correctly on the test devices. Would a test message be received fine if the configuration was wrong? Or is this normal behaviour on iOS?